# Selenium Python finding elementS

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

I wrote a code that works perfectly in one website, but in another isn't working.
Basically the problem is finding elements.

Also, tried to find it by Relative XPATH and Absolute XPATH, and still it won't find it.
(On the problematic website)

I would like to minimilize sharing, if anything else would help tell me :)
working element:

```
<div id="areaAvail_0" class="areaAvail red button" style="top: 141.65px; left: 212.221px;" data-areaindex="0" data-areatype="ReservedSeating" data-areaid="f8c68849-c882-e911-80dd-984be16723b6" data-hasqtip="94">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
```

problematic element:

```
<div id="areaAvail_0" class="areaAvail red button" style="top: 213.238px; left: 91.901px;" data-areaindex="0" data-areatype="GeneralAdmission" data-areaid="20d4c178-7539-ed11-83d1-e7ab999ef3a1" data-hasqtip="1" aria-describedby="qtip-1">
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
```

The code:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=serv_obj)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 300)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    list1 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.areaAvail[data-areaindex]")
    wait.until((EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.areaAvail[data-areaindex]"))))
print(len(list1))
```

when i use the Element_to_be_clickable, it's just "stuck" in that line.
if i use time.sleep(), after the time passes it will print 0 (the problemtic website).

Any ideas or suggestions?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share your your code including links, especially to "problematic" page?

Comment: This is not enough. Also, it should be inside the question and be readable

Comment: This is absolutely not readable...Put it inside the question as a code!

Comment: sorry, i'm new here. thanks for your patience!
edited :)

Comment: Elements are seem to be the same. So, we need to see the page containing it and all your code. Again, based on current information we can't help

Comment: Since in the first place i tried to minimize because of comment's char limitation, i edited again and posted the full element code.

Comment: OK, I see, but still... Missing basic debugging information.

Comment: Thank you.
I would like to know what kind of information will help?
in the problematic website there is just one element (the one that i attached) and the 
length of the list is 0, while in the other website there are elements. The elements structure is the same as i posted.

Comment: It may help. your actual selenium code is important too. We can\t promise we will help. We can only try. But currently we are missing basic details

Comment: @Gilhmm : Have you provided `implicit/explicit` wait before accessing the elements? If so and still getting no such element, please check element isn't inside an `iframe`?

Comment: Thanks you both for the replies.
I edited the code again, maybe it might help.
i dont what iframe is,  but the elements are the same. still one can be inside an iframe in contrast to the other?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So @KunduK was right! it was inside an iframe.
thank everyone for your time! very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is solved.
It was indeed inside an iframe
in order to click the element inside the iframe, i used these lines:

```
wait.until((EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#myIframe"))))
wait.until((EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.areaAvail[data-areaindex]"))))
```

thanks everyone!